# Как ограничить число для ввода в UITextField (Swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть UITextField, и нужно чтобы пользователь не мог ввести в него число меньше 1 и больше 100.
(Именно не количество символов, а число)

Есть метод - shouldChangeCharactersIn range, но что-то не получается его использовать и для ограничения по MAX и по MIN:

```swift
    import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
      @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
      var maxValue = 100 {
        didSet {
          textField?.text = nil
        }
      }
    }
    
     
    extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
      func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
        let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if newText.isEmpty {
          return true
        }
        else if let intValue = Int(newText), intValue <= maxValue {
          return true
        }
        return false
      }
    }
    
    protocol AsyncGeneratorType {
      associatedtype Element
      associatedtype Fetch
      func next(_ fetchNextBatch: Fetch)
    }
```

Нельзя вводить 0 и отрицательные числа. И числа более 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно - проверяем вхождение в диапазон

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let minValue = 1
    let maxValue = 100
    lazy var valuesRange = minValue...maxValue

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    
    if newText.isEmpty {
      return true
    }
    
    return valuesRange.contains(Int(newText) ?? minValue - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Дополнение: необходимо еще добавить @IBAction на событие Editing End, чтобы работало